# Run a function on complete of div fade out using mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools, fade

I am new to mootools and use jQuery normally.

In jQuery i know I make a function run after the effect has been completed like so.

```
$('#id').fadeOut(500, function(){ // Run function on complete. });
```

But how do you do it with mootools? So far I have:

```
$('id').fade('out');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the options for the tween/fade.

```
var el = document.id('id');

el.set('tween', {
    onComplete: function(){
        // Run function on complete
    }
});

el.fade(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons I prefer mootools is the way the code flows...

However if you like chaining everything together like jQuery you can do the same in mooTools

```
$('id').set('tween', {
    onComplete: function(){
        // Run function on complete
    }
}).fade(0);
```

And do it all in one chunk of code